Manga (I think its a manga) where the female lead is reborn because she committed suicide, i think?
I saw in a recap, but they never told me what the name of the manga was.
It starts with, I think the female lead (FL) named Stella and her sister, that's apparently not her sister and they were both adopted by this one duke guy that already had two sons that were weirdly exact copies of him. Then she shows how her sister, which I think is named Cynthia, took care of her when they were in the duke's mansion(? I don't know). Then she kinda screwed her over and took some kind of magical powers from her and her father suddenly hated her? But her sister didn't tell her that she actually took Stella's powers and she tricked her and said that Cynthia gave her powers to Stella and that made her feel bad for a long time, until she died.

Is this A World Without You...?

After being taken in by the noble house of Nacht, Sienna grew up with her adopted sister, Lorena, who she believed to be the sweetest, kindest person in the world. But after Lorena attempts to kill her, Sienna realizes how much her "loving" sister actually hated her. She tries to end her life with a magic potion but ends up going back in time instead. Determined to survive, she tries to use her memories to her advantage. For some strange reason though... Lorena is now nowhere to be found.


The female lead, Sienna, is an orphan who lived in an orphanage for children with magical aptitude, until she was adopted by the Grand Duke, Rodrik Nacht, who has black hair, red eyes, and two biological sons who share those traits.
When Sienna arrives at the Duke's mansion, she meets Lorena Minanchy, an older girl from a noble family who was also adopted by the Duke. Lorena is outwardly sweet and charming towards Sienna, but uses deception to steal for Sienna's magical power for herself. Sienna later ends up in prison, having been framed by Lorena, and commits suicide by drinking a vial of poison.
She then wakes up as her younger self back in the orphanage, on the day that she was adopted by the Duke in her previous life.
You can read the full manhwa at Tapas.
